# Delphi XE5 ресайз PNG с альфа каналом

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Проблема с ресайзом, как изменить размер чтобы сохранился альфа канал в нормальном его виде. На картинке слева - исходный png(900x900) загруженный в TImage, справа - ресайз через BitMap с использование Windows.AlphaBlend(100x100)

```
Bitmap.Assign(ImageLeft.Picture.Graphic);      
bf.BlendOp:=AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags:=0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha:=255;
bf.AlphaFormat:=0;
Windows.AlphaBlend(ImageRight.Canvas.Handle, 0,0,100,100, BitMap.Canvas.Handle, left,top,Right,Bottom, bf);
```

[image: пример]

Так вот как сделать ресайз, чтобы избежать этих артефактов?

Comment: был вроде в винде WIC какой-то раньше. там и `TWICImage` можно было в picture подгрузить. Там должны быть средства для нормального масштабирования.  Но вероятно и более новое что-то должно быть.

Comment: вон и какой то `IWicBitmapScaler` в закромах моих древних статей встречается.

Comment: @teran , да это понятно, в проект нельзя добавлять новые модули. Есть PNGImage....Надеялся, что раз Image умеет отображать и понимать нормальный альфа, то есть способ с ним работать, и я просто о нем не знаю...

Comment: что за бред нельзя добавлять модули? И какие нельзя? может какие generics.collections тоже нельзя? Я еще понимаю, что нельзя добавлять сторонние компоненты, но `vcl.graphics` то чем провинились? один черт он к проекту подключен как ни крути

Comment: @teran, `grapfics` можно, а вот `wincodec` в котором и лежит `IWicBitmapScaler`, нельзя

Comment: сочувствую. хоть какое-то обоснование этому есть? или дурь кому-то в голову попала из руководства?

Comment: Сергей, Вы используете модуль `PNGImage` для вывода `.png`-файлов?

Comment: @Dima, и загрузки и вывода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как для работы с `.png`-файлами Вы используете модуль `PNGImage`, то я бы предложил Вам воспользоваться следующим решением.

Автором компонента `TPngImage` является *Gustavo Huffenbacher Daud*.

Помимо самого компонента он (равно как и сторонние пользователи его компонента) создал несколько методов, которые позволяют выполнять определенные действия над `.png`-файлами. Все методы, какие было возможно, товарищ с EnSO - [Ryan J. Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84634/ryan-j-mills) - собрал и выложил в архиве по адресу [CodeCentral PNG Methods](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25631).

Помимо прочих вещей, там был такой код:

```
procedure SmoothResize(apng:tpngobject; NuWidth,NuHeight:integer);
var
  xscale, yscale         : Single;
  sfrom_y, sfrom_x       : Single;
  ifrom_y, ifrom_x       : Integer;
  to_y, to_x             : Integer;
  weight_x, weight_y     : array[0..1] of Single;
  weight                 : Single;
  new_red, new_green     : Integer;
  new_blue, new_alpha    : Integer;
  new_colortype          : Integer;
  total_red, total_green : Single;
  total_blue, total_alpha: Single;
  IsAlpha                : Boolean;
  ix, iy                 : Integer;
  bTmp : TPNGObject;
  sli, slo : pRGBLine;
  ali, alo: pbytearray;
begin
  if not (apng.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_RGBALPHA, COLOR_RGB]) then
    raise Exception.Create('Only COLOR_RGBALPHA and COLOR_RGB formats' +
    ' are supported');
  IsAlpha := apng.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_RGBALPHA];
  if IsAlpha then new_colortype := COLOR_RGBALPHA else
    new_colortype := COLOR_RGB;
  bTmp := Tpngobject.CreateBlank(new_colortype, 8, NuWidth, NuHeight);
  xscale := bTmp.Width / (apng.Width-1);
  yscale := bTmp.Height / (apng.Height-1);
  for to_y := 0 to bTmp.Height-1 do begin
    sfrom_y := to_y / yscale;
    ifrom_y := Trunc(sfrom_y);
    weight_y[1] := sfrom_y - ifrom_y;
    weight_y[0] := 1 - weight_y[1];
    for to_x := 0 to bTmp.Width-1 do begin
      sfrom_x := to_x / xscale;
      ifrom_x := Trunc(sfrom_x);
      weight_x[1] := sfrom_x - ifrom_x;
      weight_x[0] := 1 - weight_x[1];

      total_red   := 0.0;
      total_green := 0.0;
      total_blue  := 0.0;
      total_alpha  := 0.0;
      for ix := 0 to 1 do begin
        for iy := 0 to 1 do begin
          sli := apng.Scanline[ifrom_y + iy];
          if IsAlpha then ali := apng.AlphaScanline[ifrom_y + iy];
          new_red := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtRed;
          new_green := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtGreen;
          new_blue := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtBlue;
          if IsAlpha then new_alpha := ali[ifrom_x + ix];
          weight := weight_x[ix] * weight_y[iy];
          total_red   := total_red   + new_red   * weight;
          total_green := total_green + new_green * weight;
          total_blue  := total_blue  + new_blue  * weight;
          if IsAlpha then total_alpha  := total_alpha  + new_alpha  * weight;
        end;
      end;
      slo := bTmp.ScanLine[to_y];
      if IsAlpha then alo := bTmp.AlphaScanLine[to_y];
      slo[to_x].rgbtRed := Round(total_red);
      slo[to_x].rgbtGreen := Round(total_green);
      slo[to_x].rgbtBlue := Round(total_blue);
      if isAlpha then alo[to_x] := Round(total_alpha);
    end;
  end;
  apng.Assign(bTmp);
  bTmp.Free;
end;
```

Вот что сказал автор в описании данного метода:

> Use this method to resize RGB and RGB Alpha 'Portable Network Graphics' Images using a smooth antialiased algorithm in order to get much better results.

Результат действия кода - исходное изображение размером (1600x1078) конвертировано в изображение размером (100х100):

[image]

Как видите, альфа-канал сохранен. Цвет фона формы `clBtnFace`.

*Примечания:*

- код не изменен, все права на него принадлежат его автору(-ам).
- изображение для теста взято отсюда: [ссылка](http://imgpng.ru/download/106).